# Use a higher-resolution version of the RSS logo as the default icon for newly-created feeds

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

Currently, when you create a new feed for a chatroom, the created feed user's icon is this 32x32 image (https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon32.png):

[image]

The problem is that on the feed user's user page, it gets stretched to 128x128 and looks god-awful:

[image]

A 128x128 version of this image appears to already exist on sstatic (https://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon128.png):

[image]

Perhaps we should use that by default instead.

Comment: This seems more like a bug (IMO). It should also be relatively easy to implement.